# What is this block of memory at the beginning of heap

Tags: c, gdb, heap-memory

I'm doing some research about the userland memory allocations.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void *a = malloc(1);
    return 0;
}
```

With the above demo code, I debug the memory allocation and layout with `gdb`.

The following result shows that the `heap` section goes from `0x555555559000` to `0x55555557a000`.

[image]

But the only memory allocated in the program is starting from `0x5555555592a0`. And we can see there is one allocated chunk of size `0x291` starting from the beginning of heap section.

[image]

My confusion is what it is? All it contains are 0:

[image]

Note: I know what is the `top` chunk and other allocation behavior of `malloc` in glibc.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: It's probably the data that `malloc()` uses to track its allocations. Or it's used by some other part of the runtime library.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `_int_malloc` to catch any unexpected memory allocations, e.g. [the per-thread cache](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/source/malloc/malloc.c#L3026).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this post and although a little late I thought it might help others if I still answer the question.

Most likely that initial heap chunk of size 0x290 is the `tcache_perthread_struct` of the main thread of the program you're analyzing.

```c
// source: https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/source/malloc/malloc.c#L2906
typedef struct tcache_perthread_struct
{
  uint16_t counts[TCACHE_MAX_BINS];
  tcache_entry *entries[TCACHE_MAX_BINS];
} tcache_perthread_struct;
```

with `TCACHE_MAX_BINS=64`.

On x86_64 this results in a struct of size `64*2 + 64*8 = 640 = 0x280`. Together with the chunk header (size `0x10` on x86_64) this equals the `0x290` bytes for the first chunk.

In your screenshot it looks like the chunk has a size of `0x291` bytes but this is not correct (at least not in the likely case that you're using glibc which uses `ptmalloc`). Because chunks on the heap are aligned to `MALLOC_ALIGNMENT` bytes the last bits of the `size` header are never actually needed and have been repurposed as `A`, `M` and `P` flags.

You can find the details about the `malloc_chunk` struct [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/glibc/glibc-2.31/source/malloc/malloc.c#L1048) (The `A`, `M`, `P` flags are described in the comment after the struct definition).